# Using styled-components with gatsbyJS

Tags: css, reactjs, server-side-rendering, styled-components, gatsby

i am using gatsby-plugin-styled-components to style the elements below.

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';


const secondChar = styled.span`
  font-size: 3em;
  color: azure;
`

const TitleWrapper = styled.div`
  font-size: 3.5em;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  font-family: 'Covered By Your Grace', cursive;
`

const Title = () => (
  <TitleWrapper>
    <span>a</span>
    <secondChar>b</secondChar>
    <span>c</span>
    <span>e</span>
    <span>f</span>
    <span>g</span>
    <span>h</span>
  </TitleWrapper>
)

export default Title;
```

For some reason i simply cant figure out myself, i am unable to style the secondChar component. Color and font size doesn't change at all.
However, i am able to style the secondChar via Chrome Dev Tool.

Anyone can advise what is going on? 
Thank you.

updates:
Solved the first issue above. Forgot to use camelcase for components.

now i am trying to implement the following
[Styled-components: refering to other components](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/faqs#can-i-refer-to-other-components)

```
const SecondChar = styled.span`
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateX(20px);
  transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out;
  ${TitleWrapper}:hover & {
    color: azure;
  }
`

const TitleWrapper = styled.div`
  font-size: 3.5em;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  font-family: 'Covered By Your Grace', cursive;
`

const Title = () => (
  <TitleWrapper>
    <span>a</span>
    <SecondChar>b</SecondChar>
    <span>c</span>
    <span>d</span>
    <span>e</span>
    <span>f</span>
    <span>g</span>
  </TitleWrapper>
)
```

however hovering over TitleWrapper doesn't have any response on the SecondChar component. am i doing something wrong again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All component naming should start by capital letter, including styled components, so the `secondChar` should be `SecondChar`